# I am looking for a VBA code for the below scenario:

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a VBA code for the below scenario:

There are four columns (A, B, C, D) in an excel sheet and the code should populate the D column.

The logic should be

- IF C2 = A2, then populate D2 with value in B2
- else if C2 = A3, then populate D2 with B3 and so on till D2 gets right value.

The columns are long lists with 400 entries.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub MySub()
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lastRow
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value Then
            Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value
        Else If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value Then
            Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i + 1, 2).Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()
Dim x As Integer
Dim erow As Integer
'erow takes in the value of the last row number.
erow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
For x = 1 To erow
    For i = x To erow
        If Cells(x, 3).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value Then
            Cells(i, 2).Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Selection.Copy
            Cells(x, 4).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            i = erow
         End If
    Next i
Next x
End Sub
```

Is this what you need. It does this for every D column not only for 2nd D column.